# How to parse xml-like text file in python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree, scribus

i have a text file in XML-like langage which look like this:

```
<StoryText>
                <DefaultStyle/>
                <para ALIGN="3" LINESP="10"/>
                <tab FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="TEXT"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="TEXT"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="TEXT"/>
                
</StoryText>
```

My goal is to parse this file in python in order to be able to replace CH= attributes content with another TEXT.

Example :

```
> <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit"
> FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5"
> TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1"
> TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"
> CH="**TEXT**"/>
```

transformed into

```
> <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit"
> FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5"
> TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1"
> TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"
> CH="**REPLACEMENT TEXT**"/>
```

I tried to use xml.etree.ElementTree library with parse and getroot methods as usual but here i got error message:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found
```

This message occurs apparently because the file is not in real XML, but a look alike.

Do you have an idea of how i could achieve this?
NB : i'm not allowed to reformat the entry file by changing its structure because this is a scribus .sla file

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
cheminout = "file.sla"
tree = ET.parse(cheminout)  # error occurs here
root = tree.getroot()
```

The file .sla is several thousands lines long one, beginning with:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?'

Comment: done, i don't understand either why the parse method is failing in error

Comment: btw the Storytext element is just a sample of the file, the real one is thousands lines long. is it possible to share the whole file ?

Comment: This, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, is a correct XML declaration (if the file is indeed encoded in UTF-8). Are you saying that the first line in your .sla file does not look exactly like that?

Comment: My .sla file begins with exactly this line, then it has thousands of lines which seems to be regular XML, but when i try to parse it with xml.etree.ElementTree methods it fails with reported error. The file is not corrupted as i can open it with scribus with no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = """\
<StoryText>
    <DefaultStyle/>
    <para ALIGN="3" LINESP="10"/>
    <tab FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"/>
    <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="TEXT"/>
    <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="TEXT"/>
    <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="TEXT"/>
</StoryText>"""


root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

for elem in root.iter("ITEXT"):
    if "TEXT" == elem.get("CH"):
        elem.attrib["CH"] = "REPLACEMENT TEXT"

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8").decode("utf-8"))
```

Prints:

```xml
<StoryText>
    <DefaultStyle />
    <para ALIGN="3" LINESP="10" />
    <tab FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" />
    <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="REPLACEMENT TEXT" />
    <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="REPLACEMENT TEXT" />
    <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Regular" FONTSIZE="10" FEATURES="inherit" FCOLOR="Black" FSHADE="100" SCOLOR="Black" SSHADE="100" TXTSHX="5" TXTSHY="-5" TXTOUT="1" TXTULP="-0.1" TXTULW="-0.1" TXTSTP="-0.1" TXTSTW="-0.1" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="REPLACEMENT TEXT" />
</StoryText>
```

Comment: i tried to execute this with the whole input file instead of the raw in line xml in xml_data var, and i got error : xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token). so i guess the problem is located elswhere in the file, not in my content sample

Answer (score 0):

I found the error : i was parsing path instead of actual file.

thanks for your time guys

Comment: "parsing path instead of actual file" - What does that mean? Not a helpful answer.

Comment: it means i was doing : tree = ET.parse(path) instead of tree = ET.parse(file)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).